# Gradle DSL method not found: 'apple()'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can i resolve this gradle error.

Error:(43, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apple()'
Possible causes:

The project 'DeChat' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'DeChat' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

build:Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.suvysoft.dechat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'

    //okhttp

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    //event bus

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
apple plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.Gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: ... **apple**?! Go away!! You're no longer my friend!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is your error:

```
apple plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It has to be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Nothing but a typo.